# MVC 5 update unknown columns in row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i need to make update in some columns in the row,but i didn't know which columns users will update it. 
there are many required fields, **may be users didn't need to update some this required filed**

```
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id,users user)
        {

                users query = db.users.Single(u => u.Id == id);


            query.username = user.username;
            query.password = user.password;
            query.confirmPassword = user.confirmPassword;
            query.email = user.email;
            query.type = user.type;
            query.photopath = user.photopath;
            query.address = user.address;
            query.note = user.note;

            db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

by this way if i update some required filed there are an error

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities.
>   See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: Because you probably set the required field to null (from your user object) so your update can't work this way. Why don't you check the value before assigning the required fields ?

Comment: no ... it has the same data (old data)

Comment: So, check out the EntityValidationErrors. Your problem doesn't come from the null values.

Comment: in laravel php there are a function make a synchronization between old data and new data when you update some required fields ,i think c# has function make this, i think it called attach(). i try it but it didn't work may be its a wrong case OR i couldn't use it

Comment: i found the problem, but there is other problem ...look at this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804112/mvc-custom-dataannotation

Answer (score 0):

check for row which needs to be Updated by using if condition before Updating
as in

```
if(!user.username.toString().Equals(query.username))//dont update it when already they are same
{
 query.username = user.username; 
}
```