# MVC Custom dataannotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

i create two custom dataannotation for this class as follow

```
public class users
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "username is Required")]
    [usernameValidation(ErrorMessage= "Sorry this name is already exist")]
     // [MaxLength(ma)]
    public string username { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is required")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("password")]
    public string confirmPassword { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [emailValidation(ErrorMessage = "Sorry this e-mail is already exist")]
    public string email { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public int type { set; get; }

    public string photopath { set; get; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string address { set; get; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string note { set; get; }
}
```

and the custom class is

```
public class emailValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    db_context db = new db_context();
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        int query = (from res in db.users
                     where res.email == value.ToString() 
                     select res).Count();
        if (query == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and other is

```
public class usernameValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    db_context db = new db_context();
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        int query = (from res in db.users
                     where res.username == value.ToString() 
                     select res).Count();
        if (query == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this annotation worked well when i create new user,

**but the problem is when i update users and didn't update username or email my custom annotation Executed, then i gives me error because username and email already exist in database.**

Comment: You need to also get the `Id` value and if its `0` (i.e. a new `users`) then use that query, otherwise use a query that excludes the `users` with that `Id` value. But is there any reason why you dont use the `[Remote]` attribute? And since both these validation attributes appear to be specific to a single property in a single class, using a `ValidationAttribute` seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom `ValidationAttribute` classes are simply checking if any `users` have the same `username` or `email`, which includes the current `user`, which causes validation to fail in the edit scenario. Since you are attempting to prevent duplicate `username` and `email`, the implementation needs to be aware of the `Id` of the `user` it is saving.

The simplest way to do this is via [`DbContext.ValidateEntity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#ValidateEntity), since it looks like you are using Entity Framework. If you are not using Entity Framework, you can use `ValidationContext` in `ValidationAttribute.IsValid` in MVC. See http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx